# How to change state (src of img) clojurescript component after reagent-render with click events

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

We have [touching clojurescript](https://conan.is/blogging/touching-cljs.html) code, but when the image changes when clicking a thumbnail the selected image needs to render with zoomer.

We start clicking the thumbnail, this changes the atom with the selected image, and passes to the zoomer code:

```
    (r/with-let [selected (r/atom (-> images first))]
        [:img.mx-auto.d-block.img-thumbnail {
          :src        thumbnail_small
          :on-click   #(reset! selected img)}]

        [:div.col-sm-10
              [zoomer selected]
         ]
        ]])
```

To mount the component with the image url. Passes url of the original size of the image `zoomer [image]` when rendering the **component-did-mount** (first time) works `[:img {:src   image`, but when clicking in another image, the atom reacts but does not "rerender":

```
(defn zoomer [image]
   (let [!hammer-manager (atom nil)
         !zoom           (atom {:x 0 :y 0 :scale 1})
         !start-zoom     (atom {:x 0 :y 0 :scale 1})]

    (r/create-class
     {:component-did-mount
     (fn [this]
       (let [mc (new js/Hammer.Manager (r/dom-node this))]
       (println this.add)
       ;; Pinch
       (js-invoke mc "add" (new js/Hammer.Pinch))
       (js-invoke mc "on" "pinchstart" #(do (reset! !start-zoom @!zoom)
                                            (.preventDefault %)))
       (js-invoke mc "on" "pinchmove" #(let [{:keys [x y scale]} @!start-zoom]
                                        (reset! !zoom {:x     (+ x (.-deltaX %))
                                                       :y     (+ y (.-deltaY %))
                                                       :scale (* scale (.-scale %))})
                                        (.preventDefault %)))
       (reset! !hammer-manager mc)
      ))

   :reagent-render
   (fn [_]
     [:div.zoomer
      [:img {:src   image
             :style (transform @!zoom)}]])

   :component-will-unmount
   (fn [_]
     (when-let [mc @!hammer-manager]
       (js-invoke mc "destroy")))})))
```

I saw this example [Using Stateful JS Components](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Using-Stateful-JS-Components.md) with G Maps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

1.- Change `:reagent-render` to `:render`.

2.- In `:render` add a `let` with `reagent/argv` to take the params. This forever take the second `[_ **image**]`:

```
 :render
 (fn [this]
   (let [[_ image] (r/argv this)]
     [:div.zoomer
      [:img {:src   image
             :style (transform @!zoom)}]]))
```

Is optional to write a param here: `(defn zoomer [image]`. This works `(defn zoomer []` if we use `r/argv` it this found the params.

This example helped me 
[Allowing lifecycle metadata on inner component fns](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/issues/47#issuecomment-61056999) and this [documentation of reagent method form 3](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md#form-3-a-class-with-life-cycle-methods).